# Character in Java don't update with post increment

Tags: java

I want to get next character and I am writing the code like this

```
char c = 'A';
c = c++;
System.out.println(c);
```

The printed character is A. But if I use preincrement operator with 'c' then I get next character (B). Here is the code with preincrement operator.

```
char c = 'A';
c = ++c;
System.out.println(c);
```

Can someone explain the difference?

Comment: The `c = ` assignment occurs after the post-increment, overwriting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The increment operator doesn't make sense if you assign that result back to the variable. Doing

```
c = c++;
```

takes the return value of `c++`, which is `'A'`, and assigns that to `c`. Instead, simply do

```
c++;  // or ++c
```

In your case, you probably want to do

```
System.out.println(++c);  // prints 'B', and |c| is now 'B'
```

Comment: Most probably wants to do `System.out.println(++c)`, as `System.out.println(c++)` would still print A even though `c` will be set to 'B'.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou thanks, edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

`c = c++;` means, first the current value will be used and then it will be incremented. Therefore it's first printing the current value

```
c = c++;
System.out.println(c);
```

translates to:

```
c = c; // since the actual value is returned first
System.out.println(c);
```

and hence, the value `A` get printed.

Whereas

```
c = ++c;
System.out.println(c);
```

translates to

```
c = c+1;
System.out.println(c);
```

Comment: The first example doesn't increment `c` at all if is a local variable (a field would be incremented for a very short time before the assignment resets it, possibly leading to multithreading issues)

Comment: @Carcigenicate , oh my bad...thanks for correcting :)